# Put some data in MongoDB collection every 5 minutes

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, iot

I have IoT application that monitors humidity and temperature in my room and displays it in html page that I created. Now I need to put data in MongoDB database. Temperature and humidity data is updated every 2 seconds and I think that is too much information for database. I want to store that info in database every 5 minutes. What function can I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**, I think you might be able to use the `setTimout()` function of javascript to call a function that gets the sensor data and puts the data into `mongodb` every 5 minutes.

```js
function getData(){
 //Code here to get sensor data and put it into database
}

setTimeout(getData, 300000);
```

Docs: [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/).

You can use a loop to wrap the `setTimeout()` function so that it calls `getData()` function every 5 minutes.

Keep in mind that the time is passed in milliseconds.

Comment: @narutouzumaki It's my responsibility as a programmer to help fellow programmers.